# Aggregate function in inline view

Tags: sql, pervasive

I am trying to write some SQL for Pervasive database but I can't get my query working.

let me present a simple example. Imagine I have the following table:

PURCHASES:

```
OrderNumber     CustomerName
 55             Amy
 56             Dan
 57             Bob
 58             Dan
 59             Dan
 60             Bob
 61             Amy
 62             Cindy
 63             Dan
```

now I can use the query `select count(OrderNumber) as "Number of orders palced", CustomerName from PURCHASES group by CustomerName order by count(OrderNumber) desc` to get this result for the inline view:

```
Number of orders placed                CustomerName
          4                            Dan
          2                            Amy
          2                            Bob
          1                            Cindy
```

But I don't want to stop here I want to know how many customers exist for each "Number of orders placed" but I can't get this query right.

I want to use this as a subquery something like this:

```
select x."Number of orders placed",count(x.CustomerName) as
       "Number of customers that have purchased this many orders" from 
(
    select count(OrderNumber) as "Number of orders placed", CustomerName from PURCHASES 
    group by CustomerName 
) x
group by x."Number of orders placed"
```

my query is failing miserably I think because column labels is not the proper way to refer to the the subquery.
The result I want to get should look like this:

```
Number of orders placed           Number of customers...
      4                            1
      2                            2
      1                            1
```

help and explanation is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing wrong in your query except for `order by` in the inline view.

```
select x."Number of orders placed",count(x.CustomerName) as
       "Number of customers that have purchased this many orders" 
from 
(select count(OrderNumber) as "Number of orders placed", CustomerName 
 from PURCHASES 
 group by CustomerName
) x
group by x."Number of orders placed"
```

Comment: sorry It meant to say order by count(OrderNumber) desc, that was a typo. editing question

Comment: order by wouldn't matter in the inline view. Use it in the outer query instead if you need it.

Comment: understood, I am not interested in the ordering really, that is an artifact of me being interested in the subquery, and then getting the idea to juice out more information from it

Comment: Thank you actually it turns out the query was fine our RDBMS was acting up.... accepted answer for good points made